# What is the best practice for keeping tsconfig.json in a subdirectory of the project root?

Tags: tsc

I have a project with /src directory at the project root and I want to keep all my configuration files (tsconfig.json included) in a /config directory. The problem is when I call tsc from the root directory passing the --project flag tsc only looks under the /config directory for .ts files. I've tried --rootDir flag in addition to --project but --rootDir seems to be overridden. I've tried including rootDir in the tsconfig.json file but that doesn't work either. Is there an attribute in tsconfig.json that will let me specify where to look for sources other than listing each file to include in the files section?